# How can I delete my Twitter account?

Tags: twitter, account-management

I've decided I don't want to use Twitter any more - how can I delete my account?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**To deactivate your account:**

1. Log in to Twitter
2. Go to **Settings**
3. Click **Deactivate my account** at the bottom of the page
4. Verify that you really want to do it and voila, it's done.

More information in [Twitter's Help pages](http://help.twitter.com/entries/15358-how-to-deactivate-your-account)

Answer (score 6):

This is pretty easy.

1. Login
2. Click 'Settings" on the top
3. Click "deactivate my account" on the bottom left

Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can deactivate your account from your account settings page by clicking "Deactivate my account" at the bottom. If you wish to use your username or email address with a future account, be sure to change them in your Settings page before you deactivate your account.